# How can I get MySql backup size?

Tags: mysql, shell, backup, dump

I have to get a backup of my database everyday and I use mysql dump with shell commands to get backup from database 
I want to know the progress of backup process .
so I need to know to the backup file size and also the file which is being created as the backup.
how can I have these ?
any answers will be appreciated .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MySQL `information_schema` table will give you meta-information about a database, including the total size for each table.  See:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

There is an example in first comment of calculating the size for an entire database.

Note however that your `mysqldump` output will have overhead depending on your output format:  integer values are represented as text, you'll have extra SQL or XML stuff, etc.

You may need to take the sizes provided and scale them up by a fudge factor to get an estimate for the dump size.

And for the dump file name:  that's chosen by you (or the shell script you're using) as an argument to `mysqldump`

Answer (score 3):

you can use the argument --show-progress-size of mysqldump.exe and read periodically the standard output.

Comment: thanks for your help , but I use it in Linux and there was not such an argument for it . would you  please explain more?

Comment: I was wondering if there's any way to determine, while mysqldump is running, how much of the backup has completed or how much is remaining?

I'd like to provide my users with a progress bar to show them the status of their backups...

thanks!

Comment: The best way I know to do this is use a second process to check the file size one way or the other. eg: ls -l grep.log | awk '{print $5}' or one of many synonyms.